# PHP Twitter API problems?

Tags: php, twitter

A site I manage uses the [my_twitter.php class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4075-PHP-Set-and-retrieve-Twitter-user-status.html) simply to receive tweets from one certain account. As of a few hours ago this has stopped working, it displays a wrong username / password message while the credentials are correct.

On [various websites](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/08/twitter-login-errors/) I am reading about API problems but I'm not sure if the my_twitter class needs to be replaced with another one that uses OAuth, or will the problems be resolved and my_twitter start working again? That class is [still listed as an official library](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php) by Twitter.

EDIT: turns out I do not need OAuth to just receive the latest tweet. http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show This link explains things well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from an email I received from Twitter this morning, titled '**Update: Twitter Apps and You**':

> **Update 1: New authorization rules for
>   applications**
>
> Starting August 31, all applications
>   will be required to use “OAuth” to
>   access your Twitter account.
>
> What's OAuth?
>
> - OAuth is a technology that enables
>     applications to access Twitter on your
>     behalf with your approval without
>     asking you directly for your password.
> - Desktop and mobile applications may
>     still ask for your password once, but
>     after that request, they are required
>     to use OAuth in order to access your
>     timeline or allow you to tweet.
>
> What
>   does this mean for me?
>
> - Applications are no longer allowed to
>     store your password.
> - If you change
>     your password, the applications will
>     continue to work.
> - Some applications
>     you have been using may require you to
>     reauthorize them or may stop
>     functioning at the time of this
>     change.
> - All applications you have
>     authorized will be listed at
>     http://twitter.com/settings/connections.
> - You can revoke access to any
>     application at any time from the list.application at any time from the list.

So it does look like you need to find another library, that uses OAuth.

Comment: Agreed it's just that libraries like this one seem awfully complex to just receive the latest tweet. http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo

Answer (score 0):

Quote from twitter received email:

> Some applications you have been using
>   may require you to **reauthorize** them or
>   may stop functioning at the time of
>   this change.

Comment: Understood but this is for applications like Tweetdeck, AFAIK. Not simple classes that retrieve your latest tweet.